# File lost using mv

Tags: mv

Went to directory where 7z file was located. Used this command

```
mv file.7z /Home
```

I was logged in as root to get to the directory where the file was located and launched the command as root. Now I can't find the file anywhere. Searched Home folder as root and as user with

ls -la

But still no joy. I know the file has been moved as the original directory is now empty.

Comment: Did you type `Mv` or `mv`? `/Home` or `/home`? Capitalization matters. Probably you should look for a *file* called `Home` in the `/` directory.

Comment: Sorry it was mv and capital H for home

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your file is not lost, it has just been moved to the root directory and renamed to `Home`.

You should find a file in your root directory called `Home`.  This will be your file.

**Why this happened**

The filesystem in unix/Linux is **case-sensitive**, meaning that `home` and `Home` do not refer to the same thing.  While you probably intended to move it into a directory called `home`, you used a capital `H`, so it did not find such a directory and instead interpreted your command as a request to move it and rename it to a new file called `Home`.

**Solution**

Always use the correct case.  You could also have prevented this happening by adding a trailing slash after the directory name, eg.

```
mv file.7z /Home/
```

This would cause it to look for `Home` as a *directory*.  If it didn't find such a directory, then instead of renaming it to `Home` as a file, it would have failed.

Comment: The home directory is spelled with a capital H. Also when I typed

Comment: mv file.7z /Home/

Comment: I got an error stating no such directory exists. I will search the root for a file called Home. Thanks for info

Comment: @0_insomniac_0 the *nautilus bookmark* corresponding to your *home directory* is spelled with a capital `H` - but that isn't an actual directory called `Home` (in fact, it's most likely something like `/home/username`)